# Add component to dom on click of button in angular2

Tags: angular

I have personInvolved component. This component has personDetails component. There is a button in personInvolved component. Onclick of the button I need to append the personDetails on DOM. each time I click it should append the personDetails component. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to remove the component and create it again each time? Or do you want to keep adding an instance on every click?

Comment: I want to add that component template URL each time

Comment: Then the below answer by @JB Nizet is the approach you should take.

Comment: How can I remove or pop the array in personDetails component. PersonDetail is having a button called remove

Comment: You're going to have to use a service. Take a look at this doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `*ngFor`:

```html
    <button (click)="addPerson()">Add person</button>
    <person-details *ngFor="let person of persons" [person]="person"></person-details>
```

And in the component code:

```js
    persons: Array<Person> = [];

    addPerson() {
        this.persons.push(new Person());
    }
```

Comment: Here personDetails is other component having templateURL. I need to append the personDetails on click of addperson button in personInvolved component. First time it will append one <person-details>. Next time it should append one more persondetails on click.. And so on

Comment: What is new Person() method here ?

Comment: How can I remove or pop the array in personDetails component.  PersonDetail is having a button called remove.

Comment: The person-details component should not be the one removing itself from its parent component's model. Either put the delete button out of the person-details component, or have it emit an event (using an EventEmitter), and listen to this event in the parent component to know that delete has been clicked and that the component should thus be removed from the array.

Comment: I have used eventEmitter, but how can I manage the index for which one to delete. I can able to pop the array but couldnot find which one has been clicked..Can you please help me

Comment: I have got the solution