# How apply styles from Material Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material2

I need to add a button with the Material Angular 2 style. So I have a button that does this:

```
<button mat-button (click)="addElement($event, 'button')">Add button</button>
```

Where addElement is defined:

```js
addElement(ev, tag) {
    const htmlElem = ev.currentTarget;
    const el = this.renderer.createElement(tag);
    this.renderer.setAttribute(el, 'mat-button', '');
    el.textContent = 'New Button';

    htmlElem.parentNode.insertBefore(el, null);
  }
```

Clicking on the button then creates a new element in my HTML, shown as:

`<button mat-button">Add button</button>`

The function code correctly generates the button, however it doesn't apply all children as shown in the original button code from the [material code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/button/button.html)

So do I have a way to "refresh" the button so that the everything from the standard Mat-button applies to the button added via the JS code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219997/add-component-to-dom-on-click-of-button-in-angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to generate the buttons dynamically but I would do it something like this

In your template:

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="addNewButton()">Add new </button>
<div  *ngFor="let btn of buttonsList">
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">
  {{btn+1}}
</button>
</div>
```

In your component:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  buttonsList = [];

  addNewButton():void{
    const newId = this.buttonsList.length;
    this.buttonsList.push(newId);
  }
}
```

You just have to loop through your array and display the buttons. Every time you add a new button, you just have to push a new value to your array and let the framework do the heavy lifting.

Here's the stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7rfwrx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Actolia I think this solution is more suitable for your question.

Comment: Hey that's way simpler and exactly the kind of logic that fits my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Actolia no problem. glad to help

Answer (score 2):

### What went wrong?

You are right that you have added the mat-button attribute but since you are creating a button dynamically you did not be able to achieve to generate the whole structure of mat-button.

Below is the whole style and structure of mat-button

```
<button class="mat-button" mat-button="">
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">Add button</span>
<div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple"></div>
<div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

As you can see there are other html elements in the mat-button which includes ripple effects and focus overlay.

---

### The Solution to your question

We are going to use Angular Renderer to create html element, set the attribute to the element and to append it on an element.

### So what we did

create the button that will trigger the append

```
<button id="clickBtn" (click)="onClick()">Click here to add Button</button>
```

import the import `Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2` in the component.

```
{ Component, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

add a directive that will target the html element where the button will get appended (#clickBtn [is the id tag of the button that we created)

```
@Directive({ 
     selector: '#clickBtn' 
})
```

create a constructor to inject renderer and elementref

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,private elRef: ElementRef)   { 

}
```

trigger the click event to append the button

```
    onClick() {
     const btn = this.renderer.createElement('button');
     const span = this.renderer.createElement('span');
     const div1 = this.renderer.createElement('div');
     const div2 = this.renderer.createElement('div');

     const text = this.renderer.createText('I am a Generated Button');

     const attrBtn = this.renderer.setAttribute(btn, 'class', 'mat-button');
    const attrSpan = this.renderer.setAttribute(span, 'class', 'mat-button-wrapper');
    const attrDiv1 = this.renderer.setAttribute(div1, 'class', 'mat-button-ripple mat-ripple');
    const attrDiv2 = this.renderer.setAttribute(div2, 'class', 'mat-button-focus-overlay');

     this.renderer.appendChild(span, text);
     this.renderer.appendChild(btn, span);
     this.renderer.appendChild(btn, div1);
     this.renderer.appendChild(btn, div2);
     this.renderer.appendChild(this.elRef.nativeElement, btn);
   }
```

Woah so what going on here. as you can see we generate here all the structure of the mat-button

To know more about Renderer2 Please visit this link.

https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

---

Please see the link of live code on stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dmgrave-ng-so-answer-dom?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Hope this helps.

Comment: **Please don't post the link very big. Thanks.** Also, **don't** use **bold** all the time.

Comment: @Edric Understood. Sorry about that. I will not do it again.