# Remove a specific component instance from an array in parent on a button click in child based on some condition in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, parent-child

I have a case where I want to remove an instance of a component from an array (in parent component) on a button click from inside child component based on some condition.

[image]

In the image, 'Add BU' button is in parent component and the three text fields below (namely 'BU', 'G Value' and 'C Value') and one cross button are coming from child component.
On each 'Add BU' button click a new row from child component is created in UI.
I used the following code to push instances of child to an array in parent :-

[image]

[image]

Now I have question regarding 2 points here :-
1. How may I delete the same specific child instance from the array in parent, on the same instance cross button click (cross button is inside child) ?
2. How may I send the values added in each text field in each row (i.e. 'BU', 'G Value' and 'C Value') on 'Add' button click ?

Some similar question has already been asked in here and I have used similar approach given in the accepted answer : [Add component to dom on click of button in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219997/add-component-to-dom-on-click-of-button-in-angular2). And my first question is also being asked as the last comment in image below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the child instance:

```html
<payment-option
    *ngFor="let bu of buList; index as i"
    (delete)="removeBU(i)>
</payment-option>
```

```js
removeBU(i: number) {
  this.buList.splice(i, 1);
}
```

To get the data on add:

```js
@ViewChildren(PaymentOptionComponent) paymentOptionComps!: QueryList<PaymentOptionComponent>;

add() {
  const data = {};
  this.paymentOptionComps.forEach(comp => {
    // Get data from comp and add to data here.
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Collierre for your response and yes it resolved my first issue. But second one still hangs in there. I don't know whether I am not understanding it well or what but I am still not able to access data from child to add.
So on debugging your given code, when I hovered over 'comp' it still gives instance information of 'PaymentOptionComponent' but not the actual values of the fields 'BU', 'G Value' and 'C Value'.
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got following as response :


I got following as response : 
> deleteRow: EventEmitter
 _isScalar: false
 observers: [Subscriber]
 closed: false
isStopped: false
hasError: false
thrownError: null
__isAsync: false
__proto__: Subject
selectedPaymentOption: "G/L_CC"
buttonClicked: true
__proto__: Object

------------->
Now how can I extract my required information from this is the question.

Comment: Are you able to do something like `comp.bu`, `comp.gVal`, `comp.cVal` etc.? I can't be more specific with my suggestions without seeing the code for `PaymentOptionComponent`.

Comment: No I am not able to get. Probably I am missing something from my side. Below is my code for the component 'PaymentOptionComponent' :

Comment: import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'payment-option',
  templateUrl: './payment-option.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-option.component.css']
})
export class PaymentOptionComponent  {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() public selectedPaymentOption: string;
  @Input() public buttonClicked: string;

  @Output() public deleteRow = new EventEmitter();

  public buVal: string;
  public gVal: string;
  public cVal: string;

  public removeRow() {
    this.deleteRow.emit();
  }
}

Comment: <div style="display: flex;" id="addBU_ID"
  *ngIf="buttonClicked && selectedPaymentOption && selectedPaymentOption === 'G/L_CC'">
  <input-text label='BU' style="width: 26.6%" mandatory #buValue [(ngModel)]="buVal"></input-text>
  <input-text label='G Value' style="width: 26.6%" mandatory #gValue [(ngModel)]="gVal"></input-text>
  <input-text label='C Value' style="width: 31%" mandatory #cValue [(ngModel)]="cVal"></input-text>
  <icon icon="cancel" title="Remove this row" (click)="removeRow()" size="s"
    style="margin-top: 10px; cursor: pointer;">
  </icon>
</div>

Comment: Hey @Collierre, I have added my code. Sorry that it is not properly formatted. Don't know how to do that here in comments section.
Kindly help and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ok then you should be able to do `comp.buVal`, `comp.gVal`, `comp.cVal`. If that doesn't work then I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: When I am trying to print 'comp.buVal' or any other value, though they don't give any compile time error in my script file but they all are coming out to be undefined.
Am I missing something here ? Or can you please suggest a better approach ?

Comment: I figured rest of the problem :)